# Что за ошибка Laravel

Tags: laravel

Залил проект на сереер и появилась ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: PHP версию повыше поставь. С 7.3 100% будет работать.

Comment: Переустановил до 7.4 не помогло

Answer (score 0):

Дело было действительно в версии php, после установки забыл применить

```
sudo a2dismod php7.0
sudo a2enmod php7.4
```

Всем спасибо